# Running a tcl file in Network simulator

Tags: network-programming, tcl, simulator, ns2

I have made a .tcl file to simulate  **Gossiping-based Ad Hoc Routing**. When I try to run it using NS 2.35 I am getting the following error:

```
xgridsz=, ygridsz=
Sim.: utime/stime: 67 10    stack/heap: -4192 4591616
num_nodes is set 0
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl

couldn't read file "": no such file or directory
while executing
"source.orig {}"
("uplevel" body line 1)
invoked from within

"uplevel source.orig [list $fileName]"
invoked from within
"if [$instance_ is_http_url $fileName] {
set buffer [$instance_ read_url $fileName]
uplevel eval $buffer
} else {
 uplevel source.orig [list $fileName]
 ..."
(procedure "source" line 8)
invoked from within
 "source $val(cp)"
(file "simAODVG.tcl" line 155)
```

The link of my tcl file is given below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OEPsG0ILELSHhMQzZQdW5STW8/view?usp=sharing

How will I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

---

Line 155 , `""` :

> couldn't read file `""`: no such file or directory

Answer : `""` is defined in line 18 : `set val(cp)   [lindex $argv 1]`

...... and `argv 1` seems **not** to be defined anywhere ?

---